# Is SQLite up to this task? Storing path names along with file properties

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite

Currently I am looking for an embeddable database (C++, Win32) and I found SQLite quite charming. However, I'm wondering whether it even makes sense to store file paths along with the file properties in an SQL database. The number of files can run from a few hundred or thousand into the millions or billions on a server system. This is for a software that explores the disk contents (not the contents of the files themselves, though).

What I was thinking about would be a table to store the full directory part and another to store the file properties (including the name). The latter would then contain a back-reference to the "parent" folder.

One thing I am considering as well is whether the directory table should store the full path for each directory, which would lead to storing redundant information such as:

```
ID | Name
0  | C:
1  | C:\Windows
2  | C:\Windows\System32
3  | C:\Windows\System32\config
```

instead of:

```
ID | Name     | Parent
0  | C:       | NULL
1  | Windows  | 0
2  | System32 | 1
3  | config   | 2
```

Of course I cannot get "greedy" about saving storage/memory and also store a single instance of each string (each path component), unless there is some kind of pruning or reference counting ...

Which one would you consider superior and why? Wouldn't the second method impose a performance penalty?

Also, are there any projects out there that are [FLOSS](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/FLOSS) and have implemented something similar (storing hierarchical path names along with properties), preferably already with SQLite?

---

In the schema I am thinking about, the file `C:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE` would be represented by something like:

```
ID | Name   | Folder | Size    | Attributes | ...
42 | SYSTEM | 3      | 1024000 | 0x00000301 | ...
```

Comment: How many paths are you going to store?

Comment: Why do you need 2 tables? Files/paths only have one lot of settings don't they?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: because it seems awfully wasteful to store the exact same path components over and over again.

Comment: @Tichodroma: the whole disk content on an arbitrary Windows system. It can be a few thousand to millions or billions on a server system.

Comment: Why would you be storing it over and over again? Are you saying path `C:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE` could have more than 1 set of properties?

Comment: It depends on how much storage can SQLite handle. I would personally go for the option of storing the Parent folder information so that later on you can have the option of accessing a folder using the relationship of the current folder (for example: `(current_folder_name_here)\..\..\..\` can be translated in your application to something like `[The great-great-grand parent of (current_folder_name_here)]`

Comment: No, but `C:\Windows\System32\config` (the containing folder) can have more than a single file. So why throw something different (files vs. folders) into the same tables?

Comment: The directory table shall not store full paths. Please, do not pretend that the filesystem is a tree, in fact it is a DAG and could be an arbitrary graph if we had admitted this years ago. In fact the name of a directory or a file should be stored within the parent directory, as it done in the filesystem, instead of the actual file. The same file may have different names and paths.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I didn't say it's a "tree" I said it's hierarchical. And so it is. Being a DAG doesn't void that statement at all. I'm looking for advice/suggestions ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L: the thing is that neither of your proposed structures is capable of representing the fact that, for example, `C:\Windows\System32\config` and `C:\my_junction_points\alias_for_config` might represent the same directory. Your second table gives each row a *unique* name and parent, which is inconsistent with each file having a *unique* folder, on account of the filesystem being a DAG -- entities have multiple parents. Unless, that is, you treat NTFS reparse points as leaves in your structure, turning it into a tree (or forest of multiple drives).

Comment: @SteveJessop: exactly what I intend to do. Reparse points, no matter whether junctions or symbolic links or, as a special case, volume mount points are treated specially and can be easily detected merely on account of an attribute bit being set. Still, you raise a very good point here. But I think it is possible to represent it in a similar manner the file system does (including the possibility of breaking the "link"). I also think I understand the point Ash was trying to make earlier now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite should easily be able to handle this. See the [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

I'd prefer the second, self-joined form of your table. SQLite should have problem following the ID contained in the `Parent` field back to the `ID` (which should have an index). But the `Name` field should have an index, too. This will enable quick lookup of existing folders when you insert a new entry into the table.

Comment: Do you reckon that separating the name strings out into yet another table and merely storing the indexes into that one makes sense or is this more or less a performance loss with no real gain to weigh it off?

Comment: Names and properties logcially belong together, don't they?

Comment: of course, but names can (and will) get repeated. Holds for both the path components and the base file names themselves.

Comment: "the Name field should have an index, too" - I would expect that an index on the pair (parent, name) in that order would be more useful. If I want to record a new path "C:\config", I don't care that there's already a file/directory called config *somewhere*, I care whether there's one in the root of C.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I get what you mean and I agree. However, storage (whether on disk or in memory) *is* a very real issue as I know from experience. So if I can squeeze out a sizable percentage without much performance loss by storing strings separately, I'd prefer that.